# Why don't this toggle animation execute in all browsers

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle

This file isn't executing in any browser other than firefox on mac. Added everything i can think to get it sorted.

http://samhorner.co.uk/dev/samhorner/

Clicking on the twitter bar should close it, then open it again when you click on it again, only one click works on the other browsers. The blue box is a flash area in the background.

Thanks or the help.

Cheers

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra float causing some weird behavior here, just remove it to fix:

```
<div id="list" style="overflow: hidden; width: 412px; ">
```

The `click` handler is working, but since it's floating the width is just being hidden because it's parent also has `overflow: hidden`.  If you're dynamically collapsing nested overflow/floated elements like this, they won't re-expand properly, at least not in a cross-browser way.  Luckily in your case the float is extraneous, just remove it and your current jQuery code will work fine :)